# How can I load the default controller when class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to setup CI such that when a URI match is made it follows the standard method of calling the method of the matched class, but when no class is matched, it calls the default class instead?

For instance, lets say I have the following controllers defined:

```
controllers/main.php
controllers/page1.php
```

- When the URI is `localhost/Main` then `controllers/main.php` class
  matches (standard CI)
- When the URI is `localhost/` then the    `controllers/main.php` class
  matches (assuming default controller is    defined in
  `config/routes.php`)
- When the URI is `localhost/Page1` then the `controllers/page1.php`
  class matches (standard CI)
- When the URI is `localhost/Undefinedpage` then I want the
  controllers/main.php to be matched.

Note I can't list this explicitly in the `config/routes` because I
   don't know what the actual text is.

I also don't want to do wild-card match because it would prevent the normal operation of CI.  I also don't want to setup a route for each controller - that would be silly.

A 404 over-ride is close to the operation I want, but the 404-override doesn't prevent a 404 from being issued - so that solution is not valid either.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What is your CI version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/routes.php`

```
$route['404_override'] = 'controllers/main';
```

> when ever user visits some other URL, **CI will ditect that as 404 and redirect to above controller**

Comment: What's the consequence of "It won't affect to the show_404() function, which will continue loading the default error_404.php"?

Comment: What ever the value you give in `404_override` it will load